# VSTO - Best place to store Excel workbook settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsto

I have a legacy Excel AddIn implemented in VBA which I am slowly porting to .net using VSTO. Using this AddIn I am storing settings per workbook within a hidden sheet. I was wondering if there is a better approach to do this using VSTO.

Comment: Do you have access to a database that you can store the settings to?

Comment: no unfortunately not, it all has to be standalone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Custom Document Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhxe2d75.aspx) to store the settings.

Comment: Looks good, I will have to give it a go and see if I can store everything I need in there.

Comment: Unfortunately I will stick to the hidden sheet approach for my metadata purely because custom document properties are quite limited.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Can I ask what stops you in using CDP's? We had settings shared by different application so the settings are stored in ini file. The path for the ini file and the value to lookup in ini files are stored in CDP's.

Comment: I almost need to serialise a number of objects in there with ArrayLists which I don't think you can do with CDPs. At least I don't have the time or the luxury to experiment with this.

Comment: Seems to be complex, Good luck!